# Excessive Oil Consumption, is there a leak?

Tags: oil, oil-leak

I own an Audi A4 2008 and lately every few hundred kilometers the oil runs low (so I add oil of course).

- I tried to look for oil marks under the car, sometimes I see something that looks like oil and sometimes I don't see anything, so I'm not sure.
- There is no color to the smoke that comes out of the exhaust, seems fine there.
- There is no smoke coming from under the hood or anyplace else.
- I smelled burned oil only once, today, when I started the car after it hasn't been moved for two days.
- I should state that the intake manifold gasket was replaced about a year ago (I had burned oil smoke).

What can be the cause? an oil leak? If so, can it be spotted in one of photos I attached?
If you see an oil leak, what should be replaced?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How *much* oil do you add every few hundred kilometers?

Comment: Did you wipe down parts of the engine before taking photos? If not, oil seems to be leaking out of the filler cap.